# Post/Redirect/Get in Webkit causes a full page reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, safari, google-chrome, webkit, post-redirect-get

It seems that in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari) when a Post/Redirect/Get is performed on the server, the entire page (html + images + css, etc.) is redownloaded. It appears the same as if you reloaded the page.

There's been a question (and somewhat of a solution) posted in the Google Chrome Help: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=72bf3773f7e66d68&hl=en

Does anyone have a more elegant way of doing this? I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and would prefer to not write a custom Redirect result that returns Javascript or the actual page based on the UserAgent.

Should I just hope and wait that Webkit will change its behavior?

Comment: What if you set a Far-Future Expires header for your static resources, does that help?

Comment: It seems to ignore any caching mechanisms that may be in place. It looks like it behaves in the same way as if the user clicks the Reload button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full page reload on Post/Redirect/Get ignoring cache control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004702/full-page-reload-on-post-redirect-get-ignoring-cache-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. The only "workaround" I've seen untill now is to use a Refresh header instead of a Location header to do the redirecting. This is far from ideal.

[Bug 38690 - Submitting a POST that leads to a server redirect causes all cached items to redownload](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38690)

Also, this question is a duplicate of "[Full page reload on Post/Redirect/Get ignoring cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004702/full-page-reload-on-post-redirect-get-ignoring-cache-control)".

Comment: Thanks so much for the input and pursuing this issue. Hopefully it gets fixed one of these days.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Cache-Control: public` header.